# What books are in your parenting reference library?

Tags: books

There are alot of books about parenting. Some are better than others. Which book(s) do you turn to as general, all-purpose, parent guides?

Comment: On these Stack Exchange sites, questions are usually about specific problems you are facing. This is a very broad, generalized poll of the community and not really appropriate for this type of Q&A site. I have to close this, but if you have other questions about parenting, please feel free to try again. Thanks.

Comment: I think this is a great question and equivalent to the following stackoverflow question. So long as everything is community wiki, I don't see the harm. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read

Comment: Given the nature of parenting, which is largely unscientific, identifying useful resources is an important aspect of the topic. One could argue that most of the questions on this site are a poll of the community. In this case, I would suggest that you leave the question open. Another way to word this, making it more specific, would be: As a new parent, I am looking for a reference that addresses most early-childhood issues. What would you suggest?

Comment: This question needs 3 more votes to re-open. If you think this a question that should stay, click on re-open!

Comment: @nGinius, I've created this question instead: [What elements make a parenting book good?](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/1150/what-elements-do-you-look-for-in-a-good-parenting-book)

Comment: I agree with nGinius and Javid that this question, as a community wiki, could be a valuable resource.  I think torbengb's new question is also great, but distinctly different from this one.

Comment: I'm surprised people can still down-vote a closed question. And no comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://cb.pbsstatic.com/xl/03/0003/9780380570003.jpg

How to Talk So Kids Will Listen & Listen So Kids Will Talk

Comment: I've heard great things about these authors and their other book! What's the message in this one?

Comment: Key message: don't deny your childrens emotions. Listen to what they say when they're upset, and get them to express themselves. Don't tell them "don't be sad, it's just spilled milk", instead tell them, "I see that you're sad, I get sad when I spill milk too".

Answer (score 0):

[image]

What's Going On In There?